# Problems using cfAES

Tags: compact-framework, bouncycastle, opennetcf

I need to use HMACSHA256-Encryption on a Windows CE device.

I tried to use BouncyCastle / cfAES (in combination with OpenNETCF), but I can't get them to work.

BouncyCastle: I always get the error "Missing method exception: " regard macUtilities.GetMac-method.

cfAES: There's a whole bunch of error messages... "Type or namespace 'HashAlgorithm' not found" and so on...

What's the best practice to use cfAES or BouncyCastle on .NET Compact Framework? Where are the pitfalls? What are the requirements for cfAES (which version of OpenNETCF)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built BouncyCastle 1.7 for the Compact Framework back in 2011 with no problems.  I put [the solution on my blog](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2011/07/28/BouncyCastleCryptoInTheCompactFramework.aspx) since there was no way to add an attachment here.

For the OpenNETCF solution, the latest versions of the SDF have have HMACSHA256 already in it - why are you pulling in cfAES as well (Casey merged in his code long ago).

Comment: Thx, I'm using the solution from your blog now. It works without problems.